# Fano manifolds and positive Ricci curvature.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I already know that if a Kahler manifold, $M$, is Fano, then $M$ has Kahler metrics with positive Ricci curvature. What about the converse? If $Ric(M)$ is positive, does this mean that $-K_M$ is ample?

Comment: It's the other way around: Ricci positive means exactly that $ -K_X$ has a positively curved metric, so it is ample. The converse is not true, some kind of stability condition on $ T_X $ is needed; see recent work by Tian and Donaldson & co.

Comment: Thank you. Though a question of mine is what are the condiitons for the converse to be true? I actually saw the converse in this book: (Corollary 7.3) http://books.google.com/books?id=e9mp7QXSxO8C&lpg=PA86&ots=Xc3znCT3Os&dq=Ricci%20curvature%20positive%20implies%20Fano&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q=Ricci%20curvature%20positive%20implies%20Fano&f=false

Comment: I think the work of Tian and Donaldson and Co. are on Kahler Einstein metric. In your case, both directions are true. One direction is proved in the  corollary you stated. The converse is easier, as ampleness is equivalent to positivity by the Kodaira Embedding theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, I misunderstood and thought you were asking about Kahler-Einstein metrics. As an apology, here's a real answer.

If you just want Kahler metrics instead of Kahler-Einstein ones the situation is relatively simple:

Let $M$ be a Kahler manifold of dimension $n$ (no compactness needed). It is equivalent to give a smooth Hermitian metric $h$ on $K_M$ and to give a smooth volume form $dV$ on $M$. This holds because given a volume form $dV$ and local sections $\sigma,\tau$ of $K_M$ we can define $h$ by
$$
i^{n^2} \sigma \wedge \overline \tau = h(\sigma,\overline\tau)\, dV.
$$
Conversely, given $h$ the same equation defines a volume form $dV$.

Suppose now that we have a Hermitian metric $\omega$ on $M$. This defines a volume form $dV$ and thus a metric $h$ on $K_X$. A standard computation shows that one of the three Ricci curvatures of $\omega$ is
$$
\operatorname{Ric} \omega 
= - \frac{i}{2\pi} \Theta_{K_M,h}
= \frac{i}{2\pi} \Theta_{-K_M,h^{-1}}.
$$
Thus, if $M$ admits a Kahler metric (in which case all the three Ricci forms are equal) with positive Ricci curvature, then $-K_M$ is ample.

The converse, as pointed out in Ballmann's book, is true but a little trickier (and needs compactness of $M$). Given a positive Hermitian metric on $-K_M$ we pass to a volume form and then have to find a Kahler metric which has that volume form (the problem can be formulated in different ways; we can also look for a Kahler metric with a given Ricci form). There's no problem to find such a Hermitian metric, but to get a Kahler one we have to solve some hard PDEs.

A more delicate question is whether we can take the Kahler metric $\omega$ to be a Kahler-Einstein metric. Up to scaling and normalization, this means that we want a Kahler metric $\omega$ such that $\operatorname{Ric} \omega = \omega$. The simplest example of such a thing is the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb P^n$. Now, if we have such a metric, then clearly $-K_M$ is ample because the Ricci curvature is positive. However, there are compact Kahler manifolds with $-K_M$ ample that do not admit Kahler-Einstein metrics (the simplest one is maybe the projective plane blown up in 9 well chosen points). The work of [Tian](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4669) and [Chen, Donaldson and Sun](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7494) (and others) is aimed at finding the necessary and sufficient condition for a manifold with $-K_M$ ample to admit a Kahler-Einstein metric. If the preprints in the links are correct, this happens when the tangent bundle $T_M$ is stable in some sense.

Comment: The anticanonical class of the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at $9$ points is not ample. Moreover, stability of the tangent bundle is not terribly similar to the notion that CDS and Tian work with. One does however know that KE implies stable tangent bundle, the converse was conjectured by Yau but is now known to be incorrect.